# Android Universal ImageLoader in ListView scrolling very slow

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have a ListView with items which have various numbers of images. Each item was put into a HorizontalScrollView with a horizontal LinearLayout, and I add ImageViews dynamically into the LinearLayout.

I used [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load images from local sdcard asynchronously. I set the ImageLoaderConfiguration in the onCreate method of custom Application class:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .diskCacheSize(200 * 1024 * 1024) // 200 Mb
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

And set tha DisplayImageOptions in the constructor method of Adapter class:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_loading)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_loading_failed)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_loading_failed)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .build();
```

And I load the images dynamically in the getView method:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageURI, imageView, options);
```

My problem is, when I scroll the ListView, the image will be reloaded very slow, actually about the same speed as the first load. And it seems like each image was loaded from disk again without caching.

PS: My images are mostly taken from camera, and have a size of about 2MB ~ 3MB. I'm not sure whether it's because the original image is too large.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Try `.resetViewBeforeLoading(true)` in your `DisplayImageOptions`. You can also check with `.delayBeforeLoading(100)`

Comment: did you give permission :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Try to use AndroidQuery instead of Universal Image-Loader AndroidQuery : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: @Chirag Jain I have the permission. And I can see the log of ImageLoader: Cache image in memory [file:///....jpg_1080x1800], but if I go to that dir I can't see the cache files. I got no warning message indicating if the cache failed.

Comment: @Skynet I tried .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) but still reloading very slow. Thanks.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Currently most of my images is from local sdcard, and seems like that Android Query is for network files?

Comment: yes please try read more info from given source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found what's happening.

**For short: cached image is too large.**

I used a relative size of ImageView: [wrap_content, match_parent] instead of setting fixed size. So the ImageLoader cache the max possible size of all the images as I saw in the log which is my device size: 1080x1800. And that is also very large and cause slow reloading.

**To solve it:**

Set fixed size of your ImageView. Or if you don't want to, set the max possible width and height of the ImageView. After I set the max height, my images were cached to 250x250 and the loading delay was almost gone.

See [Useful Info](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) for more information.